# I want to edit my xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Hi I am working on XML file, here I want to give rights to user to edit my xml file nodes to his own custom language.

I am enclosing my code, but it is not editting my xml file. Need assistance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //The Path to the xml file   
        string path = "D://Documents and Settings//Umaid//My Documents//Visual Studio 2008//Projects//EditXML//EditXML//testing.xml";

        //Create FileStream fs  
        System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        //Create new XmlDocument       
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmldoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        //Load the contents of the filestream into the XmlDocument (xmldoc) 
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        //close the fs filestream            
        fs.Close();
        //Change the contents of the attribute        
        xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0].Attributes[0].InnerText = "Umaid";

        // Create the filestream for saving      
        FileStream WRITER = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        // Save the xmldocument      
        xmldoc.Save(WRITER);
        //Close the writer filestream 
        WRITER.Close();

    }
}
```

My XML file which I am going to edit, but couldn't.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rule id="city" scope="public">
  <one-of>
    <item>Boston</item>

  </one-of>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = "D:\\Documents and Settings\\Umaid\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\EditXML\\EditXML\\testing.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        var itemNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("rule/one-of/item");
        if (itemNode != null)
        {
            itemNode.InnerText = "Umaid";
        }
        doc.Save(path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you really want to do with your XML?? Which attribute to you want to change??

One hint: you can load and save XmlDocument to a path directly - no need for the filestream .....

```
xmldoc.Load(@"D:\yourpath\file.xml");

xmldoc.Save(@"D:\yourpath\newfile.xml");
```

The problem is that your expression `xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0]` selects the `<one-of>` node which has no attributes.

You cannot change a non-existing attribute.

If you want to change the "id" attribute of `<rule>`, you need to do this on the DocumentElement:

```
xmldoc.DocumentElement.Attributes["id"].Value = "Umaid";
```

If you want to change the text inside the `<item>`, do this:

```
XmlNode itemNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/rule/one-of/item");
if(itemNode != null)
{
   itemNode.InnerText = "Umaid";
}
```

Marc